# github change account in github remote

Tags: git, github, git-bash

i just started github today and i made a new repository for "git remote test" it's working fine so far im just a little curios about how you can change account
[image]

the "happdevcode' is my second account that i used to push a commit into my main account repository and when i change the account through `$ git config user.name` and `$ git config user.email` it didn't ask me for a password does that mean you can use anyone's account as long as you know the email and username?

Comment: Either you left your repo open for anyone to commit to, or you are using SSH or name/password authentication, which are separate from the user name/email on commits. Which is it?

Comment: i didn't use SSH and i did make my repo public but i don't know if it's related. My question is if somehow i have your username and email will that mean i can use your account to commit to my repo? because when i changed the `user.name` and `user.email` from my gitbash it didn't ask for my password

Comment: Again, those are not credentials; they are just the defaults used as the author on the commit. But Git lets users commit as other people, by default, yes. You're not 'using an account'; you are just setting pieces of text associated with the commit and its message. A commit has an author and a committer, and it's legitimate to e.g. commit something yourself but set someone else as the author, e.g. if they had a great idea to fix something but told you about it on the phone while they were nowhere near anything with Git access.

Comment: thanks a lot that clears up my confusion

Comment: i asked that question because i thought anyone can view anyone's email and that will make everyone's name too accessible

Comment: Then make the repo private, or have users commit under pseudonyms, or whatever you want... but the default is to have info out in the open, probably because it's open-source!

Comment: If you have other questions, you should probably make a new post here for each, rather than leaving them in comments. But you should search first to check if someone already asked/answered each one.